# how do I get a 4 mic system with 6.5mm to be source for PA?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, microphone, wireless

I have this wireless mic system: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07XJ6VVBC/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XJ6VVBC)

and this cord:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000068O1K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000068O1K)

It seems to plug in perfectly when I place cord into my normal PA system. But all I hear is a buzz. Doesn't seem like any of the mics are sending in audio. And using an old iphone as source with 3.5mm converter to this PA works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile stating any information about what you are doing.  Are batteries in the senders?  Have the senders been switched on?  Does their channel match the receiver channels?  Has the receiver been switched on?

At any rate, the specification for the line output is *one* mixed output, balanced or imbalanced.  That will be a *mono* output.  The usual connection to a PA worth its name is using a balanced cable with 6.3mm TRS plugs on both ends.  It's kind of unusual for a PA to have RCA inputs, and a TRS to 2×RCA cable is the wrong cable anyway.  You could use a *mono* TS to single RCA cable, but a balanced cable will have quite better signal quality, assuming that your PA actually has a balanced input.

Comment: Hi thanks, the PA is this one https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0797XPMRL and re: Are batteries in the senders? yes  Have the senders been switched on? yes  Does their channel match the receiver channels? yes  Has the receiver been switched on? yes

Comment: i think i need https://www.amazon.com/Tisino-Balanced-Signal-Interconnect-Quarter/dp/B07J5R6T1N/ and just stop using RCA.

Answer (score 0):

You require multiple XLR-XLR balanced audio cables to connect the devices. You are not using the correct cable.